# Disable Custom Pricing From Orders Created in Admin For Products with MAP applied

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I am hoping someone can help me out with this. I have searched for a long time and can find no answer.

Is there any way that I can disable the 'custom price' checkbox when creating an order from the admin panel based on specific attributes of the product?

I oftentimes offer customers a lower price but do not want to be able to do so if the product has MAP applied.

Is there any sort of 'if' statement I can apply here or any other solution that could help me?